# How do I convert a BitmapImage image to data so I can upload it to the web on a HTTP POST request with Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'd like to take a BitmapImage and POST it to a PHP page I have on a server. The page then creates a .jpg file on the server for me.

How can I convert that image into data for HTTP POST? Here is a shortened version of what I have been using for my Objective-C code on the iPhone to give you an idea of what I'm looking to do:

```
// We need to resize the images before uploading to the server.
resizedImage = [resizedImage resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit bounds:CGSizeMake(h,w) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage, 0.9f);

// setting up the request object now
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

/*
add some header info now
we always need a boundary when we post a file
also we need to set the content type

You might want to generate a random boundary.. this is just the same
as my output from wireshark on a valid html post
*/
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

/*
now lets create the body of the post
*/
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", barcode]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

I understand this is a pretty complicated topic with a large amount of code. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

First you convert the image to a byte array:

```
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
byte[] postData = stream.ToArray();
```

Then you create a POST request using [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).

**UPDATE(on comments below):**

I realized that you cannot use the above code in Silverlight/Windows Phone 7.5.
But, you can use WriteableBitmap and copy it's pixels into a byte array.

Example:

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

WriteableBitmap wbm = new WriteableBitmap(bi);

int w = wbm.PixelWidth;
int h = wbm.PixelHeight;
int[] p = wbm.Pixels;
int len = p.Length;
byte[] result = new byte[4 * w * h];

// Copy pixels to buffer
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++, j += 4)
{
    int color = p[i];
    result[j + 0] = (byte)(color >> 24); // A
    result[j + 1] = (byte)(color >> 16); // R
    result[j + 2] = (byte)(color >> 8);  // G
    result[j + 3] = (byte)(color);       // B
}
```

result should contain the byte array.

Comment: The bmp.Save method and System.Drawing don't seem to exist for me. I'm using Windows Phone 7.5 SDK.

Comment: The code you posted won't work on Silverlight/WP7. He's trying to encode a [`BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), not a [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The following code should be fine (it's not tested).

First, you have to convert your [`BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to a [`WriteableBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) object and encode it into a JPEG stream using [`Extensions.SaveJpeg`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.extensions.savejpeg%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Then you can post your stream with[`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), in particular using the [`OpenWriteAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144218%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method and the [`OpenWriteCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openwritecompleted%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event.

```
string uploadUri = "http://www.myuri.com";

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

// This event will be raised when we are ready to send data to the server
webClient.OpenWriteCompleted += (s, args) =>
{
    var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);
    // Write the encoded image into the result stream
    writeableBitmap.SaveJpeg(
        args.Result,
        bitmapImage.PixelWidth,
        bitmapImage.PixelHeight,
        0,
        100);
};

// This event will be raised when writing is completed
webClient.WriteStreamClosed += (s, args) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("Upload Complete");
};

// Write to the WebClient
webClient.OpenWriteAsync(new Uri(uploadUri), "POST");
```